# unable to find possible memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I having a warning when i analyze my code for memory leak from xcode. I tried for hour to figure it out but couldn't understand, but i have some suspicion on specific code:

```
[stack push:[outputString copy]];
[stack print]; //here xcode tell there is potential leak of an object that is createn on above line
```

and my stack implementation is:

```
-(void) push:(NSString *)element{
[store addObject:element];
top++;
}

-(void) print{
NSLog(@"%@", [store objectAtIndex:top]);
}

- (void)dealloc {
[store release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

and this is my init for my stack class:

```
-(id) initWithMutableArray{
self = [super init];
if(self){
    store = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    top = -1;
}
return self;
}
```

My suspicion is on code [outputString copy]. But i am storing it on array and i am releasing store array on dealloc.
Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `release` to balance the `[outputString copy]` so it is leaked. When adding the object to your array it gets retained by the array and released when the array is destroyed.

Comment: i.e. replace `[stack push:[outputString copy]];` with `[stack push:[[outputString copy] autorelease]];`

Comment: So it means i shouldn't be worried about warning then since i am releasing my array on dealloc ?

Comment: No, you are leaking memory there. Do as Matthias suggested

Comment: yeah thanks. But could u explain me. I need to understand. I know there is no balance release for it. But eventually that object is going inside array and array retains it. SO how it will affect my program in future ? Gracias.